# How can I extract parameter names and values from within a currently running stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm building a stored procedure to log table/procedure and need to be able to pull (not specific to current stored procedure) all parameter names and values. This would then be inserted into that `Log` table.

I'm hoping there is a one-liner (or a loop) function that will grab the info.

I've only seen articles about accessing `sys.objects` to identify parameters so far and this seems counter-productive and will be a performance hit.

This will be run on multiple stored procedures so can't require manually naming/calling the parameters.

Comment: _so can't require manually naming_ Yes you can - you just don't want to. There is no alternative to accessing the actual parameter values either. And you cannot know if the value passed was actually passed or is the default value defined for that particular parameter.

Comment: There is no way of doing this. I know because I've had reason to look into this as well. T-SQL cannot reflect over its own execution stack. Capturing actual parameter values is possible only through a trace or extended event session that captures RPC events, which is a possible alternative if you don't have to do it so much from *within* the stored procedure.

Comment: OK, so if I extract the defined parameters from sys.parameters.  Can I get the provided value using the variable that contains the Parameter Name?

Comment: @aSystemOverload - your most recent question was already answered. "T-SQL cannot reflect over its own execution stack."

Comment: @SeanLange to clarify, was your comment in response to the initial post or to my question about getting the parameter value using a parameter name stored in a variable?

Comment: Both really as they are asking almost the same thing. You could probably kludge together some code that you would need to stick into all your existing procedures that could look at sys.parameters and generate some dynamic sql to populate a table valued parameter that you could pass to your logging procedure but it would be dreadful to maintain.

Comment: Getting the parameters of the currently executing stored procedure is not the problem (`select * from sys.parameters where object_id = @@procid`). It's getting the current values that's the impossible bit. Notably, you will find you cannot use dynamic SQL to pass in the parameters in a generic fashion -- that's because the values of those parameters are not available within the new batch you start that way, and there is no generic mechanism for passing parameters without knowing them.